# Cannot connect to Apache server from outside even on the same network

Tags: python, django, apache

I am using Apache 2.4.12 64bit on Windows server 2012 R2. The backend is Python 3.4 Django 1.7. When I am trying to connect on localhost all is fine, but when i tryied to connect from outside even on the same network, I have no luck. No answe, even no 403 forbidden. Tis is my Apache config:

```
Alias /media "C:\SourceTree\AT\AT_OP\media"
Alias /static "C:\SourceTree\AT\AT_OP\static"

<Directory "C:\SourceTree\AT\AT_OP\static">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:\SourceTree\AT\AT_OP\media">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / "C:\SourceTree\AT\AT_OP\AT_OP\wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "C:\SourceTree\AT\AT_OP"

<Directory "C:\SourceTree\AT\AT_OP\AT_OP">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AuthType None
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

I noticed, that when i restart the server this among all the messages pop up.

```
[Sun Mar 08 09:16:54.962900 2015] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 1620:tid 1036] (OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
```

Can this? be the problem?

Comment: Sounds like you cannot connect at all. Either the server is not listening to requests from the outside or you have a firewall blocking such requests.

Comment: Its the same problem even when i turn off firewall

Comment: So the server does not listen to request from outside, but only binds to the loopback interface (that is why "localhost requests" get through). Take a look into the main http server configuration. You are looking for the "Listen" statement, the default configuration depends on the distribution of the apache http server you installed, so on the packagers flavor. The documentation (which you _always_ should consult in case if questions...) is here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html

Comment: I have "Listen 8000", so it should listen to all ip address

Comment: Then restart the http server and take a look into its error log file. Any problem pointed out there? Oh, and just to be sure: please post the relevant part of that configuration by adding it to the question above.

Comment: I addedproblem. Whats relevant part of configuration? Because I have only change Listen to my port and addded the above.

Comment: OK, just to make this really clear, _after_ you changed the `Liste` directive to `Listen 8000` you _did_ restart the http server process? And your client tries to connect to `http://some.server.example:8000/`, so _really_ to the port your http server is listening to? The suggestion Jadi made in his "answer" below is a correct step to verify this details: make a `telnet` connection from some client to that system _and that exact port_ to see if it is reachable: `telnet <ip-address> 8000`. What happens?

Comment: If you are convinced that this is all fine, then you have a problem on the network layer: if there _really_ is no firewall blocking the requests, then maybe the routing points to the wrong network or system? Do you request by IP address or by host name?

Comment: I turned off windows firewall for all sites and i am requesting my site by internal IP address.

Comment: Then this sounds like a routing problem. Or that the IP address simply is wrong. note that a system can have more than a single address.

Comment: Ah, one more question... It just occurs to me that you never really reply to a clear question. So once more, explicitly: _have you done the mentioned telnet test? Yes or no? What is the outcome? What exact command did you try?_

Comment: Note that it is not a problem if you are confused or unsure how to use such tools. All fine with that. Just ask! But there is little sense in pretending not to see such clear questions...

Comment: BTW: give it a try to change your configuration to `Listen *:8000`, restart the http server and try again.

Answer (score 3):

First try to telnet to the machine using port 80 (web) and see it the port 80 on the machine is open / accessible:

```
telnet MACHINE_IP_ADR 80
```

If you see the prompt, tell:

```
GET /
```

and see it you get any HTML output. This way you can isolate your problem one step further.

Comment: This is not an answer. It is a first step of a diagnosis.